# Nexus High disk watermark...free: 8191.9pb[-99.9%]

Tags: amazon-web-services, nexus

I have an instance of Nexus deployed in a docker container using AWS Elastic File System to store it's data.  I've been getting an error when uploading some artifacts:

```
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.etc from/to remote (http://mynexusurl/repository/maven-releases/): Could not write to resource 'com/etc/whatever.jar'
```

In the Nexus logs I can see the following message over and over:

```
high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [_atm8vFNT5qLzS5GYeNyFQ][E610BDF5-BD17F9DC-9567365A-380D6026-8419CF79][/nexus-data/elasticsearch/nexus/nodes/0] free: 8191.9pb[-99.9%], shards will be relocated away from this node
```

Seems like an integer overflow, does anyone know a way of working around this?

Comment: It looks like your disk is full?  How much free space is left on it?

Comment: Note the percentage, -99%. I have a huge amount of disk space left!  I've since moved on to Artifactory